# Which version of safe_delete is better?

Tags: c++, pointers, c-preprocessor

```
#define SAFE_DELETE(a) if( (a) != NULL ) delete (a); (a) = NULL;
```

OR

```
template<typename T> void safe_delete(T*& a) {
  delete a;
  a = NULL;
}
```

or any other better way

Comment: its still silly, but the macro safe delete should be:  #define SAFE_DELETE(a) do { delete (a); (a) = NULL; } while (0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clearly the function, for a simple reason. The macro evaluates its argument multiple times. This can have evil side effects. Also the function can be scoped. Nothing better than that :)

Comment: A macro can be scoped. It's why you commonly see macro's wrapped in `do { } while (0)`

Answer (score 17):

I would say neither, as both will give you a false sense of security. For example, suppose you have a function:

```
void Func( SomePtr * p ) {
  // stuff
  SafeDelete( p );
}
```

You set p to NULL, but the copies of p outside the function are unaffected.

However, if you must do this, go with the template - macros will always have the potential for tromping on other names.

Comment: +1 Setting a pointer to NULL after deleting it rarely makes any sense.

Comment: Settings a pointer (member of a class) to NULL after deletion could be worth the time spent to add the line to the template function or the couple of CPU cycles wasted. If you have to dig in code made by someone else with poor design that can easily spot (crashing) well hidden monster: objects that are using already deleted objects for some tenth of a second. If you aren't using a Z80, it's worth. It will save your head to blow up.

Answer (score 7):

delete a;

ISO C++ specifies, that delete on a NULL pointer just doesn't do anything.

Quote from iso 14882:

```
    5.3.5 Delete [expr.delete]

    2   [...] In either alternative, if the value of the operand of delete is the 
        null pointer the operation has no effect. [...]
```

Regards, Bodo

/edit: I didn't notice the a=NULL; in the original post, so new version: delete a; a=NULL; however, the problem with setting a=NULL has already been pointed out (false feeling of security).

Comment: About testing for NULL and performance: I know that the delete could be called with NULL, but the if(p!=NULL) is a quick read operation that could skip a function call and an assignement (write to memory). Removing the if is not wrong, but what about junior programmers that read it and what about performance?

Comment: True, on the other hand: Testing for NULL is a conditional jump. If you write your code in a way, that you normally do not free NULL pointers, you just duplicate that conditional jump, because you do it yourself and then call a function anyways, that does it again. So in my opition it's better to teach to do proper ressource tracking than to do NULL tests.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, prefer inline functions over macros, as macros don't respect scope, and may conflict with some symbols during preprocessing, leading to very strange compile errors.

Of course, sometimes templates and functions won't do, but here this is not the case.

Additionally, the better safe-delete is not necessary, as you could use smart-pointers, therefore not requiring to remember using this method in the client-code, but encapsulating it.

(**edit**) As others have pointed out, safe-delete is not safe, as even if somebody does *not* forget to use it, it still may not have the desired effect.  So it is actually completely worthless, because using safe_delete correctly needs more thought than just setting to 0 by oneself.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to test for nullity with `delete`, it is equivalent to a no-op. `(a) = NULL` makes me lift an eyebrow. The second option is better.

However, if you have a choice, you should use smart pointers, such as `std::auto_ptr` or `tr1::shared_ptr`, which already do this for you.

Comment: Neither auto_ptr nor shared_ptr sets to NULL on deletion. QPointer is the only class I know that does it.

Answer (score 2):

I think

`#define SAFE_DELETE(pPtr) { delete pPtr; pPtr = NULL }` is better

1. its ok to call delete if pPtr is NULL. So *if* check is not required.
2. in case if you call SAFE_DELETE(ptr+i), it will result in compilation error.
3. Template definition will create multiple instances of the function for each data type. In my opinion in this case, these multiple definitions donot add any value.
4. Moreover, with template function definition, you have overhead of function call.

Comment: #4 is really a non-issue. A function this trivial will surely be inlined by any half-decent compiler.

Comment: #3 is a non-issue for the same reason. In fact, I think #2 is too since ptr + 1 isn't an l-value. So basically all relevant points were invalid.

Comment: Addidionally, IF one would want to do this with a macro, one should at least use this:

#define save_delete(p) do { delete p; p=NULL; } while(0)

Think about it, if you haven't seen such a construct yet ;)

Comment: And #2 is a non-issue as well. (p+1) is an rvalue, the template takes a non-const reference. Much nicer compiler error, in fact. The macro name is unlikely to show up in an error message.

Answer (score 1):

Usage of SAFE_DELETE really appears to be a C programmers approach to commandeering the built in memory management in C++.  My question is: Will C++ allow this method of using a SAFE_DELETE on pointers that have been properly encapsulated as Private?  Would this macro ONLY work on pointer that are declared Public?  OOP BAD!!

Comment: This is exactly the reason why the C version is better, you will get encapsulation issues that are unhelpful, it's better if you can just add this stuff at preprocessor time rather than compile time.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned quite a bit above, the second one is the better one, not a macro with potential unintended side effects, doesn't have the unneeded check against NULL (although I suspect you are doing that as a type check), etc.  But neither are promising any safety.  If you do use something like tr1::smart_ptr, please make sure you read the docs on them and are sure that it has the right semantics for your task.  I just recently had to hunt down and clean up a huge memory leak due to a co-worker putting smart_ptrs into a data structure with circular links :) (he should have used weak_ptrs for back references)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this version:

```
~scoped_ptr() {
    delete this->ptr_; //this-> for emphasis, ptr_ is owned by this
}
```

Setting the pointer to null after deleting it is quite pointless, as the only reason that you would use pointers is to allow an object to be referenced in multiple places at once. Even if the pointer in one part of the program is 0 there may well be others that are not set to 0.

Furthermore the safe_delete macro / function template is very difficult to use right, because there are only two places that it can be used if there is code that may throw between the new and delete for the given pointer.

1) Inside either a catch (...) block that rethrows the exception and also duplicated next to the catch (...) block for the path that doesn't throw. (Also duplicated next to every break, return, continue etc that may allow the pointer to fall out of scope)

2) Inside a destructor for an object that owns the pointer (unless there is no code between the new and delete that can throw).

Even if there is no code that could throw when you write the code, this could change in the future (all it takes is for someone to came along and add another new after the first one). It is better write code in a way that stays correct even in the face of exceptions.

Option 1 creates so much code duplication and is so easy to get wrong that I am doubtful to even call it an option.

Option 2 makes safe_delete redundant, as the ptr_ that you are setting to 0 will go out of scope on the next line.

In summary --  don't use safe_delete as it is not safe at all (it is very difficult to use correctly, and leads to redundant code even when its use is correct). Use SBRM and smart pointers.

Comment: If you use the safeDelete to manage member pointers of a class, members well incapsulated, the assumption of having more pointer to the same data fails. The data you want to get access could be retrieved only by the object, and thanks to the safe delete any usage of the container object after its deletion could be easily spot out. Using a safe_delete on local pointer, or on only one of the pointers to the deleted data has no meaning.