# Delete pointer object in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, delete-operator

I read the following code for deleting pointer object in the open source project [X3C](http://x3c.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/x3c/trunk/code/pkg_Core/Interface/UtilFunc/SafeCall.h?revision=218&view=markup).

```
//! Delete pointer object.
/*!
    \ingroup _GROUP_UTILFUNC
    \param p pointer object created using 'new'.
*/
template<class T>
void SafeDelete(T*& p)
{
    if (p != NULL)
        delete p;
    p = NULL;
    *(&p) = NULL;
}
```

But I don't know the meaning of this line:

```
*(&p) = NULL;
```

In the above line(**p = NULL;**), p is assigned to NULL. I think it needs to do that again in another way.

Comment: That's interesting. I wonder why in the world they did that. Maybe for compiler optimisation reasons or something.

Comment: They don't do that `*(&x) = NULL;` thing for `SafeDeleteArray` weirdly.

Comment: People write weird code for all sorts of superstitious reasons. Or perhaps some compiler they were using had a bug?

Comment: @Seth Carnegie : I also think this line of code is weirdly:) And I want to find the reason for that.

Comment: @thinkhy I think we've all agreed that it's retarded pointlessness. Refer to Adam's answer below.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: These code were originally compiled in the Windows 32 bit platform using Visual Studio 2005 and Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540920/which-version-of-safe-delete-is-better/540943#540943 for a simple counter-example why this is pointless

Comment: @MSalters: Thax! Posts in that question are very detailed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's completely pointless.  Under ordinary conditions, the unary `*` and `&` operators are inverses of each other (with a few details, like that the expression `&*foo` is not an lvalue even if `foo` is an lvalue), although operator overloading can change that behavior.

However, since `T*` is always a pointer type regardless of the type `T`, it's impossible to overload the unary `operator&` for `T*`, so `*(&p)` is equivalent to just `p`, and assigning `NULL` to `p` a second time is useless.